# Tuple as argument to method in Ethereum Remix

Tags: remix, tuple

I've created this contract which allows me to perform a split payment of native tokens (ETH) or ERC20. Meaning I can send funds to multiple beneficiaries using one transaction.

Once I deploy my contract on Ethereum Remix, I then enter the tuple as requested, howver, the transaction fails as my tuple format is incorrect.

I've tried multiple combinations and cant quite get it right to get the transaction to go through.

eg I've tried

```
[["0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2", "1000000000000000000"],["0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db", "1000000000000000000"]]
```

and also

```
[[0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2, 1000000000000000000],[0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db, 1000000000000000000]]
```

With no success. Suggestions most welcome

```
from vyper.interfaces import ERC20


event Success:
    amount: uint256

struct Transaction:
    recipient: address
    amount: uint256


struct Batch:
    txns: DynArray[Transaction, max_value(uint8)]

@payable
@external 
def distribute_native(data: Batch):
    total_amount: uint256 = 0
    for txn in data.txns:
        total_amount = total_amount + txn.amount 
    
    assert msg.value == total_amount, "failed to transfer"

    for txn in data.txns: 
        beneficiary: address = txn.recipient
        beneficiary_amount: uint256 = txn.amount 
        send(beneficiary,beneficiary_amount)

@external 
def distribute(data: Batch,erc20_token:address):
    total_amount: uint256 = 0
    for txn in data.txns:
        total_amount = total_amount + txn.amount 
    
    current_balance: uint256 = ERC20(erc20_token).balanceOf(self)
    ERC20(erc20_token).transferFrom(msg.sender,self,total_amount)
    after_balance: uint256 = ERC20(erc20_token).balanceOf(self)

    assert (after_balance - current_balance) == total_amount, "failed to transfer"

    for txn in data.txns: 
        beneficiary: address = txn.recipient
        beneficiary_amount: uint256 = txn.amount 
        ERC20(erc20_token).transfer(beneficiary,beneficiary_amount)
```